# I am using HTML and Javascript to make an embedded Youtubevideo draggable. The dragging freezes when the cursor gets over the video. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api, embed

I used this (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp) tutorial to make a draggable Div, in which I then put an embedd link for a youtube video.

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #fff;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>

<p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV element</p>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>
</div>

<script>
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is, when dragging the header, it laggs a bit behind the mousecursor. This can cause the Mousecursor to be over the embedded Video. In that case, the dragging freezes, and only resumes once you are outside of the video.

So the question is: Why does this happen and how do I fix it. Or is there an alternate approach to make an embedded video positionable by the User that's better in general.

Any formatting to the question or title is very welcome, sorry if I messed up.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found an easy Solution by making the element not interactable with the mouse:

Add `document.getElementById(elmnt.id).style.pointerEvents="none";` in the function that handles.onmousedown.

Add `document.getElementById(elmnt.id).style.pointerEvents="auto";` in the function that handles .onmouseup.

Set the Header style to  `pointer-events: auto;` so that the header is still clickable and doesn't inherit the value from the Div.

Heres the updated snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #fff;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>

<p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV element</p>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>
</div>

<script>
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // UPDATED makes uncklickable on mousedown.
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id).style.pointerEvents="none";
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
    // UPDATED makes clickable again
    document.getElementById("elmnt.id").style.pointerEvents="auto";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```